# Include route helpers in javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm simply trying to log the route's root url to the console:

*app/assets/javascripts/foo.js.erb:*

```
console.log(<%= root_path %>);
```

However, that gives me this error in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

How do I include route helpers into javascript files?

Worth noting I can do this no problem:

```
console.log(<%= pi = "3.142" %>); //-> 3.142
```

However, there is a weird error when I attempt to put letters into my string:

```
console.log(<%= pi = "3.142t" %>); //-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I need to be able to log strings with letters in if I want to have my route helpers working! :)

Comment: What makes you think the helper isn't included? That would be a different error. You're not quoting the string *generated* by the helper, e.g., you're generating illegal JavaScript. There's nothing weird going on here at all, you just didn't bother looking at what you generated.

Comment: No need to be so aggressive, friend

Comment: Nothing remotely aggressive about it, although you're correct in that I take issue with skipping the most preliminary debugging steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erb is being parsed on a server side, before javascript has chance to read it. When it is executed on the browser it will read:

```
console.log(http://root_url.com);
```

You can see, that you are missing quotes here. Try:

```
console.log('<%= root_url %>');
```